# Lost Outlook.com contacts

Tags: outlook.com

I use Outlook.com and have lost all of my contacts. When I am trying to send a message I go into the `TO` section and absolutely no email addresses exist.

Can somebody tell me what to do?

Comment: Contact outlook.com support? Do you see your contacts under the "People" app?

Comment: Related: [People contact list in live and hotmail](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45042/people-contact-list-in-live-and-hotmail)

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem when I use internet explorer as my browser. If I use Firefox, my contacts miraculously reappear. So I would recommend that you try changing browser.